# want know about object sender ad event e in page load event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i tried a lot to understand this but didn't work out,what is the mystery behind the  parameters of *page load* event ,private page_load(object sender, event e){}.
can someone help me in understanding **sender** and **e** objects in page load event in asp.net that will your most kindness.

thank u.

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: actually my debugger is not working

Comment: Generally speaking the sender object represents the object that raised the event and e (EventArgs) can contain additional information about the event. So what exactly is it you do not understand? Are you running into trouble?

Comment: You should look into why your debugger isn't working. A simple breakpoint in the Page_Load method and then inspecting sender and e would tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the basics, this link may help.
See https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1117800/What-does-object-sender-eventargs-e-imply

But to use the event **sender** and **e** effectively, you will need to understand the asp.net page life cycle model.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

With these knowledge acquired, it will be easier for you the understand where you can use the two variables via the page load event.